# Activity Diagram in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uml

How can I add a UML Activity diagram to a project in visual studio 2017?

Comment: @AakashVerma this question is a _very_ poor fit over there, see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Visual Studio is a code editor, not a UML modeling tool.

There has been *some* support for UML like diagrams in VS in the past, but this has been discontinued in the latest versions.

See also this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/modeling/create-uml-modeling-projects-and-diagrams)

> Starting with Visual Studio 2017, the UML Designers have been removed from Visual Studio.